# Where can i find the story of Ashtavakra's birth and his other stories?

Tags: reference-request, ashtavakra

Where can i find the story of Ashtavakra's birth and his other stories like:

1. Giving curse to devis of swarga-loka who laughed at his crooked form?
2. Giving curse to Krishna
3. I have head an alternate story of Ashtavakra muni being cursed by a woman instead of his father Kahoda.

Please let me know the references of these and other stories of Ashtavakra if any. Thank you.